# Correct path for accessing file in webapp folder through a servlet

Tags: html, servlets

I have an "index.html" file in my webapp folder. Now i want to redirect to this file through my servlet but it always gives exception because i don't know what path to put. My code:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Must set the content type first          
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("webapp/index.html");
        try {
            view.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

> i have used "index.html", "/index.html", "./index.html",
>   "/webapp/index.html", "./webapp/index.html".

i don't know how to access this file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The first problem is that you are overriding the **service()** method. There is no reason to do that, and the [Javadoc specification for service()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) explicitly says so:

   > Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and
   >   dispatches them to the doMethod methods defined in this class. This
   >   method is an HTTP-specific version of the
   >   Servlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
   >   javax.servlet.ServletResponse) method. **There's no need to override
   >   this method**.

   So remove your `doService()` method. Instead, implement a `doGet()` method containing the code that was in your `doService()` method.
2. The second problem is that the way the html file name is specified looks incorrect. I don't know how you have structured your project, but if you placed **index.html** directly under **WebContent** you could could reference the file using **"/index.html"** or **"index.html"**. [From the specification for `getRequestDispatcher()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)):

   > The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend
   >   outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a "/" it
   >   is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

Try removing the `service()` method and adding a `doGet()` method containing your code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
    try {
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```